# Can I use google-api-java-client library for oauth2 authorization in facebook or other services that support oauth2 standard?

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client

In this Gooogle IO 11 presentation - http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android speaker has mentioned that new google-api-java-client could be used to any  rest json api.

Is it possible to use this library to authorize and use facebook graph api on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody make a sample for foursquare http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/09/05/integrate-foursquare-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the google-api-java-client to manage transport and authentication on non-Google APIs.  However, many services that support OAuth implement slight variants or have bugs that may make this difficult.  If the service is providing their own client library, it is probably best to use that (until it doesn't work, and then you should try the google-api-java-client).